# How to reference a control template from a standard control using bindings?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, custom-controls, controltemplate

I am building a custom control that inherits from the standard System.Windows.Controls.Calendar control. I'm following this article on Code Project. I also want to make the CalendarItem sub object resizable, as in this article on MSDN.

I copied the style for Calendar, CalendarDayButton and CalendarItem from the source code of the Calendar control into my custom control ResourceDictionary located in my Generic.xaml. The CalendarItem style references 3 button templates (the previous month, next month and header buttons) like this:

```
<!-- Start: Previous button content -->
<Button x:Name="PART_PreviousButton" 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        Template="{StaticResource PreviousButtonTemplate}" 
        Height="20" Width="28" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Focusable="False"
        />
<!-- End: Previous button content -->

<!-- Start: Header button content -->
<Button x:Name="PART_HeaderButton"                                             
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
        Template="{StaticResource HeaderButtonTemplate}" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
        FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10.5" 
        Focusable="False"
        />
<!-- End: Header button content -->

<!-- Start: Next button content -->
<Button x:Name="PART_NextButton" 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" 
        Height="20" Width="28" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Right" 
        Template="{StaticResource NextButtonTemplate}" 
        Focusable="False"
        />
<!-- End: Next button content -->
```

Now because this binding uses a StaticResource, i will need to copy the styles for the three buttons into my ResourceDictionary. I am not planning to do any changes to these buttons, so i am hoping that having a style for them in my ResourceDictionary can be avoided.

## Is there any way i can reference the original styles for these buttons via a binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is:

On your custom control which inherits from `Calendar`, you can expose dependency properties of type `ControlTemplate` for each of the three styles

```
public class MyCalender : Calendar
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PreviousButtonTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PreviousButtonTemplate", typeof (ControlTemplate), typeof (MyCalender), new PropertyMetadata(default(ControlTemplate)));

    public ControlTemplate PreviousButtonTemplate
    {
        get { return (ControlTemplate) GetValue(PreviousButtonTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(PreviousButtonTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    // Same for other button templates
}
```

and bind to these styles from within your `ControlTemplate` for the calendar using a `TemplatedParent` binding.

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyCalender" TargetType="viewModels:MyCalendar">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="PART_PreviousButton" 
        Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
        Template="{TemplateBinding  Property=PreviousButtonTemplate}" 
        Height="20" Width="28" 
        HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
        Focusable="False"
        />
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

I would then define a default style on the highest possible level, which assigns the button templates (`PreviousButtonTemplate`, etc.) to the dependency properties of the custom Calender Control. With highest possible level, I mean the object, in whose scope all the templates exist, which you wire together, for example *app.xaml* or your window.

```
<Style TargetType="viewModels:MyCalendar">
    <Setter Property="PreviousButtonTemplate" Value="{StaticResource PreviousButtonTemplate}" />
</Style>
```

Alternatively, you can just leave it as it is, and as long as the `StaticResources`, which the control template refers to exist during runtime, they will be resolved correctly. Not nice, though and no design time support.

**EDIT**

Ok, I didn't get you were referring to the 'original' button templates, I thought you meant templates that you already defined somewhere else. Then: No, you can't do this. I've been trying the same thing a number of times, but you can't create control templates which use parts of the original ones. There is no such thing as 'BasedOn' for ControlTemplates.

Comment: Hi Marc, that's a very interesting technique using Dependency properties. But i don't think it solves anything. Using your method, i still need to create a style/control template for the buttons, jus the binding of them is done very differently? What i am looking for is a way to refer to the already existing template from the Controls.Calendar control. I may have misunderstood something, of course :)

Comment: Ok, I didn't get you were referring to the 'original' button templates, I thought you meant templates that you already defined somewhere else. Then: No, you can't do this. I've been trying the same thing a number of times, but you can't create control templates which use parts of the original ones. There is no such thing as 'BasedOn' for ControlTemplates.

Comment: Thanks Marc :) I believe in reusing as much code as possible, so i would very much like there to be such a possibility.

Comment: Me too, it's a pain, especially when designing more complex controls. It can take a day to understand a complex control template with visual states, etc., etc.. Good luck, anyway.